# How to find parameters content in Documentation and API References

Tags: ios, core-animation

we know , class CAPropertyAnimation have a method "+animationWithKeyPath:" :

```
Apple Inc's Object-C API class :

@interface CAPropertyAnimation : CAAnimation
    + (instancetype)animationWithKeyPath:(nullable NSString *)path;
    ...
@end
```

But , I don't know how to push parameters for this method ,

So I need find API  ' Documentation And API References ' .

In ' Documentation And API References ' , I can find a description , like this :

```
Parameters
keyPath 
The key path of the property to be animated.
```

But I cannot find how to use parameter ? how to push parameters for this method ?

Can you help me ? thank you

Comment: The documentation states that `CAPropertyAnimation` is an abstract class.  You would generally want to use `CABasicAnimation` for adjusting a property. There are many articles on how to use these animations with layers.

Comment: As for paths themselves, those are generally properties associated with the layer, like `transform`, `bounds`, etc, though there are [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html) so you can do `transform.scale.y` for example.

Comment: why "frame.size.width" can not be executed ?